# Problema ao carregar imagem de um entidade

Tags: php, zend

Tenho um gerenciador de ícones, nele já consegui disponibilizar todo o *crud*.

Contudo tenho um problema, ao abrir o formulário, um `Zend\Form` para editar um ícone não consigo carregar a imagem que já está salva.

Estou usando o seguinte elemento:

```
  $element = new Image();
    $element->setName('my-image')
            ->setAttribute('src', '/assets/no_image.png')
            ->setAttribute('id','my-image')
            ->setAttribute('height', '96')                
            ->setAttribute('width','96')
            ->setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
    $this->add($element);
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Isso seria um `input type="file"` ?

Comment: Tenho um input type="file" para o upload, este elemento que postei é onde deveria ser mostrada a imagem que já está salva. Pelo menos foi mais perto disso que eu consegui.

Comment: Tá exibindo aquele ícone de imagem não encontrada? Acho que o problema é no `src`. Tenta tirar a primeira barra

Comment: A imagem que está no src aparece normalmente. O problema é carregar a imagem que vem do banco: ela nunca aparece, so a que está no src que exibida

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o helper ServerUrl conforme no exemplo abaixo:

Definindo formulário:

```
use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareTrait;
use Zend\Form\Element\Text;
use Zend\Form\Element\Image;

class Perfil extends Form
{
  use ServiceLocatorAwareTrait;

  public function init() {
    // Obtendo o helper ServerUrl
    $serverUrl = $this->getServiceLocator()
    ->get('ViewHelperManager')
    ->get('ServerUrl');

    // Criando elementos do formulário
    $name = new Text();
    $name->setLabel('Nome')
    ->setName('name');

    $avatar = new Image();
    $avatar->setLabel('Imagem')
    ->setName('avatar')
    ->setAttribute('src', $serverUrl->__invoke('/images/100x100.gif'));

    $this->add($name)
    ->add($avatar);
  }
}
```

Utilizando o formulário em uma controladora instanciando o formulário:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Application\Form\Perfil;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{

  public function indexAction()
  {
    $form = new Perfil();
    $form->setServiceLocator($this->getServiceLocator());
    $form->init();

    return new ViewModel(array(
      'form' => $form
    ));
  }
}
```

Também pode ser usado fazendo injeção de dependência pela classe Module

```
<?php

namespace Application;

use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ServiceProviderInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Application\Form\Perfil;

class Module implements ServiceProviderInterface
{

  public function getServiceConfig()
  {
    return array(
      'factories' => array(
        'Application\Form\Perfil' => function (ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) {
          $form = new Perfil();
          $form->setServiceLocator($serviceLocator);
          $form->init();

          return $form;
        }
      )
    );
  }

}
```

Chamando o serviço criado no Module.php em sua controladora:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Application\Form\Perfil;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{

  public function indexAction()
  {
    $form = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Application\Form\Perfil');

    return new ViewModel(array(
      'form' => $form
    ));
  }
}
```

Espero ter ajudado!